# Android Studio: PNG on Button

Tags: android-studio, button, png, drawable

How can I set a png icon on a button in the MainActivity?
I have to change this icon many times during the program, so I can't set the image in the xml code.

But in the xml it is in the center of the button, so it's perfect and well stretched

```
android:drawableTop="@drawable/x"
```

In the MainActivity I don't know what to do

```
bt.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, x, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
Drawable top = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.x);
bt.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, top , null, null);
```

To Add the image at centre you can use imageButton:

Add the below image button in place of your button in layout xml.

```
 <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton" />
```

Get the imageButton and set drawable:

```
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way to change width and height? and how can I put this image in the center of the button?

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting API level 17 or higher, you can accomplish this with just one simple line:

```
bt.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.x , 0, 0);
```

This method takes drawable resource ID's as arguments, so there is no need to get the drawable yourself using `getDrawable()`. Passing a `0` as argument means no icon on that side.

Good luck!

Comment: how can I put this image in the center of the button?